# How to copy and paste data from a worksheet to another in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm having a hard time trying to copy data from worksheet A and paste it in worksheet B. I'm using this simple code.

```vb
Sub CopyPasteWorksheet ()

Workbooks("New Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Export").Range("A2:D9").Copy _
    Workbooks("Repots.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Everytime I tried to run it , it pops this message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYJAG.png)

I tried different methods to copy and paste it. Still not working.

Comment: You have one or more odd characters right in front of `Workbooks("Repots.xlsm")` - maybe a non-breaking space if you copied that code from the web for example. That's adding to `Workbooks` and causing the method name not to be recognized (like `xxWorkbooks`). Try re-typing that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the destination folder and open the target file first

```
    Sub CopyPasteWorksheet ()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbtarget As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= "Location of the file\New Data.xlsx",
    Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= "Location of the file\report.xlsx",

    With Worksheets("export")
    
        .Range("A2:d9").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy


        wbtartget.Worksheets(data).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```